# Communicating between 2008 SQL Server DB and Android App

Tags: java, android, sql-server, wcf-rest

I've been doing a lot of reading about this subject and I am now of the conclusion that to communicate between a 2008 SQL Server database and an Android application, I need to create a RESTful Service to sit in between that returns JSON objects.

Would I be correct in saying that?

Comment: Yep, something like that. Some kind of service would be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need doing a server application who take data and returns to the Android application. JSON let you return complex objects.

Comment: Correct and I now have it working. To communicate between a remote SQL Server database and an Android phone easily I guess, you will need to create a RESTful Service that returns JSON objects to the phone!